# How to test asynchronous functions using mocha without callback

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, mocha.js

I have a simple function like this that has a async function inside
of it:

```
var b = function(response) {

    response = '';

    async_function(function (response) {
        response = 'test';
    });

}
```

I want to test function b to see if it sets the value of response
to "test". If not, it should raise an error. I do not want to add a parameter
for callback function for b and I do not want to wait using setTimeOut().
What is the correct way to test b using mocha (and chai)?

Thanks you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var b = function(response) {

    response = '';

    async_function(function (response) {
        response = 'test';
    });

}
```

You cant know when response will be set.

Unless you use setTimeout you cant test it,therefore you should refactor your code.